# XAML: How to use <Image> type resources declared in the Resources node?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is the first time I have to use images as resources in XAML. I have declared an `Image` type of resource inside my `Window.Resources` node, in the following way:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Image x:Key="MyIcon" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/myicon.png"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

## **How to use this resource in other parts of the XAML code?**

Must be trivial, but I didn't find any information about how to use `Image` type resources.

Obviously, using the resource as the `Source` property of the `Image` control doesn't work:

```
        <WrapPanel Background="Transparent" Height="50">
            <Image Source="{StaticResource MyIcon}"/>
        </WrapPanel>
```

The code above throws an exception while setting the `Source` property, with the following `InnerException`:

```
{"'System.Windows.Controls.Image' is not a valid value for property 'Source'."}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `BitmapImage` instead of `Image` as resource type:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="MyIcon"
                 UriSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/myicon.png"/>
</Window.Resources>
...
<WrapPanel Height="50">
    <Image Source="{StaticResource MyIcon}"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

---

You also don't have to write a full Resource File Pack URI in XAML, so you could write the resource declaration like this:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="MyIcon" UriSource="/Resources/Images/myicon.png"/>
```

Comment: Is using `BitmapImage` as resource type generally considered a better practice? If so, and you could explain it very briefly, I'll set your answer as the solution.

Comment: It is better, because Image is a UIElement (while BitmapImage is not). That makes it hard to use in multiple places, because it can't be a child of multiple parent elements. You would at least have to set `x:Shared="False"`

Comment: Besides that, when you create an Image control with a URI string for the Source property, the string is automatically converted to a BitmapFrame, a class similar to BitmapImage (both derived from BitmapSource). So you would create an Image and a BitmapFrame instead of just a BitmapImage.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I selected your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ContentControl` inside the `WrapPanel` and reuse the `Image` resource what you declared before:

```
<WrapPanel Background="Transparent" Height="50">
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource MyIcon}" />
</WrapPanel>
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, it works! I knew it must be trivial. Thanks! (Köszönöm!)

Comment: Szívesen! :) BTW you recieved another alternative answer